# How to update display command result in one line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo

I want to clear and update display text in loop without new line. I try the following code:

`echo -ne "some text\r"`

But it is not really update the line but just overwrite the line without clear the previous one. In the result, display are overlapped and display become messy.